# Async Await Handler Deadlock

Tags: .net, async-await, parse-platform, ihttphandler

I'm stuck in an Async deadlock and I can't figure out the correct syntax to fix it. I've looked at several different solutions, but can't seem to quite figure out what is causing the problem.

I am using [Parse](https://parse.com/platforms/dotnet) as a backend and trying to use a handler to write to the table. My handler looks something like:

```
public class VisitorSignupHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //Get the user's name and email address
        var UserFullName = context.Request.QueryString["name"].UrlDecode();
        var UserEmailAddress = context.Request.QueryString["email"].UrlDecode();

        //Save the user's information
        var TaskToken = UserSignup.SaveUserSignup(UserFullName, UserEmailAddress);
        TaskToken.Wait();
        ....

    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Then it is calling my middle tier:

```
public static class UserSignup
{
    public static async Task SaveUserSignup(string fullName, string emailAddress)
    {
        //Initialize the Parse client with the Application ID and the Windows key
        ParseClient.Initialize(AppID, Key);

        //Create the object
        var UserObject = new ParseObject("UserSignup")
                            {
                                {"UserFullName", fullName},
                                {"UserEmailAddress", emailAddress}
                            };

        //Commit the object
        await UserObject.SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

Although this seems to be getting stuck at `Wait()`. I was under the impression that `Wait()` would simply just wait for the task to complete, then return to normal operations. Is this not correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're running into a common deadlock problem that I describe [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

In short, `await` by default will resume its `async` method inside of a captured "context", and on ASP.NET, only one thread is allowed into that "context" at a time. So when you call `Wait`, you are blocking a thread inside that context, and the `await` cannot enter that context when it is ready to resume the `async` method. So the thread in the context is blocked at `Wait` (waiting for the `async` method to complete), and the `async` method is blocked waiting for the context to be free... deadlock.

To fix this, you should go "async all the way". In this case, use [`HttpTaskAsyncHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httptaskasynchandler.aspx) instead of `IHttpHandler`:

```
public class VisitorSignupHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
{
  public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
  {
    //Get the user's name and email address
    var UserFullName = context.Request.QueryString["name"].UrlDecode();
    var UserEmailAddress = context.Request.QueryString["email"].UrlDecode();

    //Save the user's information
    var TaskToken = UserSignup.SaveUserSignup(UserFullName, UserEmailAddress);
    await TaskToken;
    ....

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I read your blog prior to posting this and just couldn't quite figure out the syntax. This works great. Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome! P.S. Give the [TAP documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) a good read; there are some `async` conventions that would apply here, in particular renaming `SaveUserSignup` to `SaveUserSignupAsync`.

Comment: Could you please help me on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001297/how-to-check-possibility-of-deadlock-in-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are mixing synchronous and async code.  This can be done, but is tricky.  Your best bet is to make your http handler async as well:

```
public class VisitorSignupHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
    {
        public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
           //Get the user's name and email address
           var UserFullName = context.Request.QueryString["name"].UrlDecode();
           var UserEmailAddress = context.Request.QueryString["email"].UrlDecode();

           //Save the user's information
           await UserSignup.SaveUserSignup(UserFullName, UserEmailAddress);
..

        }
    }
```