# How to check possibility of deadlock in c# code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, deadlock

My application sometimes stop in the below code, not always but sometimes.

All the 3 methods `CalcQuarterlyFigures`, `CalcWeeklyFigures` & `CalcMonthlyFigures` return `Task<List<MyClass>>`.

Note, this runs inside a `foreach` loop.

```
List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();

if(i.DoCalculateAllHistory) {

    var quarterly = CalcQuarterlyFigures(QuarterlyPrices, i.SeriesID);
    TaskList.Add(quarterly);
    var weekly = CalcWeeklyFigures(WeeklyPrices, i.SeriesID);
    TaskList.Add(weekly);
    var monthly = CalcMonthlyFigures(MonthlyPrice, i.SeriesID);
    TaskList.Add(monthly);

    Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());

    if(monthly.Result.Count > 0)
        monthlyPerfFig.AddRange(monthly.Result);

    if(weekly.Result.Count > 0)
        weeklyPerfFig.AddRange(weekly.Result);

    if(quarterly.Result.Count > 0)
        quartPerfFig.AddRange(quarterly.Result);
} else {

    monthlyPerfFig.AddRange(await CalcMonthlyFigures(MonthlyPrice, i.SeriesID));

}
```

Am I missing anything here that leads to dead lock ?

Comment: What is the environment? Full .NET Framework or .NET Core? `Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());` will possibly cause a deadlock in full .NET framework. Since you already using `await` in `else` condition - use `.WhenAll`: `await Task.WhenAll(TaskList.ToArray());`

Comment: @Fabio my application is using `.NET Framework 4.6.1`.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks, let me update the code and check. Application takes almost 1 full day to complete the full run. So it might take 24 hours to confirm if its working.

Comment: @Fabio - I have a doubt. Is `await` in else condition is the problem or `Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray())` is the problem ?

Comment: If methods `CalcQuarterlyFigures`, `CalcWeeklyFigures` and `CalcMonthlyFigures` are asynchronous then `Task.WaitAll` is a problem. When you are using asynchronous methods `await` is correct approach.

Comment: @Fabio - Yeah all the 3 methods are asynchronous. So what you are suggesting is either use individual `await` in all the 3 calls or use `await Task.WhenAll(TaskList.ToArray());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In provided context (sample code of .NET 4.6.1) `Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray())` will cause a deadlock.
Definitely useful source: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

You should make you code block fully asynchronous

```
if (i.DoCalculateAllHistory) 
{
    var quarterlyTask = CalcQuarterlyFigures(QuarterlyPrices, i.SeriesID);
    var weeklyTask = CalcWeeklyFigures(WeeklyPrices, i.SeriesID);
    var monthlyTask = CalcMonthlyFigures(MonthlyPrice, i.SeriesID);

    // Task.WhenAll accepts "params" array
    await Task.WhenAll(quarterlyTask, weeklyTask, monthlyTask);

    // You don't need to check for .Count
    // nothing will be added when empty list given to .AddRange  
    quartPerfFig.AddRange(await quarterlyTask);
    weeklyPerfFig.AddRange(await weeklyTask);
    monthlyPerfFig.AddRange(await monthlyTask);
} 
else 
{
    var monthly = await CalcMonthlyFigures(MonthlyPrice, i.SeriesID);
    monthlyPerfFig.AddRange(monthly);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, instead of `quarterly.Result` can we use `await quarterly` ? similarly for weekly and monthly results ? like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32119616/3349551) uses `await` instead of `Result`

Comment: You can use `await`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help. I'll update you if the full run is completed successfully.

Comment: @Pரதீப்  `.Result` vs. `await` after `.WhenAll` is tricky... If you use `.Result` you show that you understand how all that works but on other hand people who don't will disagree and complain till you put `await` back... Overall `await` is safe if you are concerned that someone will change code by removing `.WhenAll` as not necessary.